# How to define ObjectId type of dynamic object's properties in mongoose schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The current schema looks like this:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
    filters: {
        type: Object,
        default: {}
    }
);
```

Sample Input Document:

```
{
  filters: {
    field1: "5a934e000102030405000001",
    field2: "5a934e000102030405000002",
    field3: "5a934e000102030405000003"
  }
}
```

The `filters` object property will store dynamic properties/fields but all will be `ObjectId` type,

Currently, I am using pre-hook and lodash methods to convert type into ObjectId type,

```
SchemaObj.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.filters = _.reduce(this.filters, (r, v, k) => v ? { ...r, [k]: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(v) } : r, {});
    next();
});
```

Is there any way to define ObjectId type of dynamic object fields?

I am expecting something like this if mongoose provide any other approach:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
    filters: {
        type: {
          *: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the field as a [Map](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps)

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
    filters: {
        type: Map,
        of: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }
);
```